# Why can't I see NTFS partitions on a specific drive?

Tags: fedora, mount, partition, fdisk, ntfs

I have a dual boot win10/Fedora29, with 3 internal drives:

- win10 system (NTFS)
- fedora system (ext4)
- data drive (NTFS)

I can't see the partitions on the data drive and I can't mount it.
I can properly mount my win10 system drive though.

Here is what lsblk returns:

```
$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0 118.8G  0 part /mnt/win10
└─sda2            8:2    0   452M  0 part 
sdb               8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk 
└─sdb1            8:17   0   128M  0 part 
sdc               8:32   0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sdc1            8:33   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdc2            8:34   0 118.2G  0 part 
  ├─fedora-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─fedora-swap 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─fedora-home 253:2    0  60.4G  0 lvm  /home
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The sdb drive is 3TB but only shows a 128M part on sdb1

And here is what **fdisk** returns:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128034594304 bytes, 250067567 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xee36470d

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 249135446 249133399 118.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       249137152 250062847    925696   452M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE


The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000591900160 bytes, 5860531055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 838720F4-3C3A-4339-832C-8112ABF8E9FD

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2  264192 5860532223 5860268032  2.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I don't know if the GPT corrupt message is related to sda (win10 system) or sdb (data disk)...

Has anyone an idea of how I could fix this without risking to loose data ?

Comment: The corrupt message refers to the `/dev/sdb` disk. There is a question/answer about corrupt backup GPT [that seems related here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table).

Comment: For the `/dev/sdb` disk, the end of the disk is at 5,860,531,055 sectors, but the end of the second partition is at 5,860,532,223 sectors. How did you set up the `/dev/sdb2` partition?

Comment: This disk has been formatted and partitionned under windows... Only a single volume to my knowledge.

Comment: @Torin - from your link, it seems gdisk might help rewrite or repair the GPT, I am just currently backing up all data before I do anything :)